# Why is hyperparameter 'train_size' bigger than actual trainset size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, hyperparameters

I am following the tutorial on this link:
https://cloud.google.com/architecture/clv-prediction-with-offline-training-train#cleaning_the_data

In the task.py file
(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-lifetime-value/blob/0f8c16ea70a2e7da370965e23e9e2154978364fa/clv_mle/trainer/task.py)
of the used github Repo are the default hyperparameters given.

```
# 100000 is the approximate size of our training set (to nearest 1000).
#[START hyperparams]
TRAIN_SIZE = 100000
NUM_EPOCHS = 70
BATCH_SIZE = 5
NUM_EVAL = 20
```

They are using the parameter 'train_size' = 100'000, but the actual length of the trainingset is only 883.

It is used for the following:

```
checkpoint_steps = int((train_size/batch_size) * (num_epochs/num_eval))
train_steps = (train_size/batch_size) * num_epochs
```

which in turn are used like this:

```
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(               
  initial_learning_rate = 0.096505, 
  decay_steps = checkpoint_steps, 
  decay_rate = 0.7, 
  staircase=True)
```

...and this:

```
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    input_fn = read_train,
    max_steps = train_steps)
```

I don't get it. Why is the given parameter so huge?

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at a subset, or an aggregation of the full data set? Following [this link](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Online+Retail), I see that data set has over half a million records.

Comment: @BilltheLizard In the first part of the tutorial you can see two sql files, which aggregate the data and create features. Afterwards they get split into training, evaluating and testing set. In the end the test set is only 883 rows long.